# JQuery / JQueryUI / Autocomplete not working on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, jquery-ui, autocomplete

and thanks for trying to help me out (once more) ...

Please look at this straightforward autocomplete example. The code is almost directly taken from the official docs.

```
        var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"];

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength: 0,
  })
  .focus(function() {
      $(this).autocomplete( "search", $(this).val());
  });
```

HTML is even more simple:

```
<label for="tags">Tags:</label>
<input id="tags">
```

Here is the complete JSFiddle:

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57qm2rub/5/)

The code works well on PC (tested Firefox and IE), but not at all on Android (Samsung Galaxy Tab, Android 4.2.2). When I focus the input, the autocomplete list pops up, I can select a value, but the value is never passed into the input.

I tried several combinations of JSQuery and JSQueryUI, they all behave the same. Any hints what I can do to get autocomplete work on my Tablet?

Thx

ALina.